# Fix VB Excel Macro, search and copy/paste loop, 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel, barcode-scanner

I am a novice coder. I have found a few examples and tutorials to get my code to where it is, but it returns an

> error "400"

which I have found to not be all that easy to diagnose. My goal is simple. I have a 2 sheet workbook. Sheet 1 is an order form ("PO"), and sheet 2 is a database ("DataBase"). I have this subroutine in the workbook (not one of the sheets). It prompts the user to scan a barcode, and then searches sheet "DataBase" for that part number, and then copy/pastes the next 3 cells to the right back into the original sheet "PO".

There is a little more built in, like the ability to terminate the loop if a specific barcode is scanned (xxxDONExxxx). I also am trying to find a way to to return an error message (ErrMsg2) if no match is found.

If I step through the subroutine using F8, it gets past the scanner input, and then fails the line with the note ('*FAIL*'). I would appreciate some help to get this working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub inventory()

'**** Define variables ****'
Dim partnumber As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
'Dim xxxDONExxxx As String

'**** Clear paste area in sheet "PO" ****'
Sheets("PO").Range("A17:F31").ClearContents

'**** Set row count ****'
lastrow = 100 'Sheets("DataBase").Range("B500").End(x1Up).Row

'**** select first cell to paste in****'
Range("A17").Select

'**** loop for scanning up to 30 lines ****'
For i = 1 To 30

    '**** Prompt for input ****'
    partnumber = InputBox("SCAN PART NUMBER")

    '**** Abort if DONE code is scanned ****'
    If ("partnumber") = ("xxxDONExxxx") Then GoTo ErrMsg1

        '**** search DataBase for match in B, copy CDE /paste in PO BDE****'
        For x = 2 To lastrow

        If ("partnumber") = Sheets("DataBase").Range("x, 2") Then '*FAIL*'
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Sheets("DataBase").Cells(x, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Sheets("DataBase").Cells(x, 2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Sheets("DataBase").Cells(x, 3)

        End If

        Next x

Next i

ErrMsg1:
MsgBox ("Operation Done - user input")
ErrMsg2:
MsgBox ("Part Number does not Exist, add to DataBase!")
End Sub
```

Sheet 1 - "PO"

[image]

Sheet 2 - "Database"

[image]

Comment: It should be `If partnumber = "xxxDONExxxx" Then`, remove all the double quotes `"` around **partnumber**, and `Sheets("DataBase").Cells(x, 2).Value`

Comment: You seems to keep pasting into the same cell (`A17`) 30 times or until done string. Also consider use formulas to lookup Description, Qty, Price, so only need loop to fill in Item# (change the database range to a Table and name it appropriately).

Comment: use Worksheets instead of sheets and reference a workbook before that:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(.....)
You can set this once:
Dim dbSheet As Worksheet
Set dbSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
dbSheet.Cells(.....)

Comment: looks like good code below.  You can also use a Vlookup and skip the loop, if looking for a single match.  There are a few ways to search a range for a match.  Just a thought.

Comment: Will - I like that idea to name the worksheet path as dbsheet, much cleaner to code that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are more efficient ways to do this, but this will do what you expect:

```
Option Explicit

Sub inventory()
'**** Define variables ****'
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = Sheets("DataBase")
Dim wsPO As Worksheet: Set wsPO = Sheets("PO")
Dim partnumber As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim Found As String
Found = False
'**** Clear paste area in sheet "PO" ****'
wsPO.Range("A17:F31").ClearContents

'**** Set row count on Database Sheet ****'
lastrow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'select the last row with data in the given range
wsPO.Range("A17").Select

ScanNext:
'**** Prompt for input ****'
partnumber = InputBox("SCAN PART NUMBER")

'**** Abort if DONE code is scanned ****'
If partnumber = "xxxDONExxxx" Then
    MsgBox ("Operation Done - user input")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Selection.Value = partnumber
End If

'**** search DataBase for match in B, copy CDE /paste in PO BDE****'
 For x = 2 To lastrow
     If wsPO.Cells(Selection.Row, 1) = wsData.Cells(x, 2) Then
         wsPO.Cells(Selection.Row, 2) = wsData.Cells(x, 3)
         wsPO.Cells(Selection.Row, 5) = wsData.Cells(x, 4)
         wsPO.Cells(Selection.Row, 6) = wsData.Cells(x, 5)
         Found = "True"
     End If
 Next x

 If Found = "False" Then
     MsgBox "Product Not Found in Database!", vbInformation
     Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
 Else
     Found = "False"
 End If


If Selection.Row < 31 Then
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    GoTo ScanNext
Else
    MsgBox "This inventory page is now full!", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code exactly, and it didn't bring up any errors, but didn't do anything else either. I will keep looking to see if I can figure out why.

Comment: why value 2?  You could drop it from both sides and it should work.  sometimes I will use .value but don't usually use value2.  I would use a number as a column as well.  You can always use predefined double variable like varDouble = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Database").Range("BA33).Column to assign the column or the row.  Handy trick to define the col or row as numbers when you don't want to count them (lots of cols),

Comment: careful with xlDown most prefer an xlUp to determine the last row

Comment: LastDR = CalcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @JoeGambino I've updated my answer, I've tested it this time and it should work for you now, let me know if any issues...

Comment: @Xabier - you nailed it. It even leaves all the results when you scan a part number that isn't in the database. Which is good, then we know which one needs to be added. Thank you. I +1'd you and marked your answer as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of application.match. For example:

```
If IsNumeric(Application.Match(LookUpValue, LookUpRange, 0)) Then
startCol = Application.Match(LookUpValue, LookUpRange, 0)
Else
MsgBox "Unable to find " & LookUpValue & " within " & LookUpRange & ". Please check the data and try again. The macro will now exit"
End
End If
```

This tests if the item exists in the dataset, then does something with it if it exists. If it doesn't exist, you can throw an error message. Massaging it slightly for your needs:

```
If IsNumeric(Application.Match(PartNumber, DataBaseRange, 0)) Then
'Do things with matching
Else
'Do things when you don't have a match
End
End If
```

Comment: I was able to make this work, but I like your suggestion and I am going to make some notes about it. I will use it in the future I am sure. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful comments as well as accepting the one that answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rethink version. You should create a Sub to add new unknown items into the Database range, otherwise you need to quit current process, add new item into Database, then **rescan** all items from beginning!

```
Option Explicit

Sub inventory()

    '**** Define variables ****'
    Const STOP_ID As String = "xxxDONExxxx"
    Const START_ROW As Long = 17 ' based on "A17:F31"
    Const LAST_ROW As Long = 31 ' based on "A17:F31"

    Dim partnumber As String, sDescription As String, i As Long
    Dim oRngDataBase As Range

    '**** Clear paste area in sheet "PO" ****'
    Worksheets("PO").Range("A17:F31").ClearContents

    ' Determine the actual database range
    Set oRngDataBase = Intersect(Worksheets("DataBase").UsedRange, Worksheets("DataBase").Columns("B:E"))
    i = START_ROW
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        partnumber = InputBox("SCAN PART NUMBER")
        If Len(partnumber) = 0 Then
            If partnumber = STOP_ID Then
                MsgBox "Operation Done - user input", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
                Exit Do
            End If
            sDescription = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partnumber, oRngDataBase, 2, False) ' Description
            If Len(sDescription) = 0 Then
                If vbYes = MsgBox("Part Number (" & partnumber & ") does not Exist, add to DataBase Now?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) Then
                    ' Suggest you to create a new Sub to insert data and call it here

                    ' Update the Database Range once added new item
                    Set oRngDataBase = Intersect(Worksheets("DataBase").UsedRange, Worksheets("DataBase").Columns("B:E"))
                End If
                'NOTE:  Answer No will skip this scanned unknown partnumber
            Else
                Worksheets("PO").Cells(i, "A").Value = partnumber
                Worksheets("PO").Cells(i, "B").Value = sDescription
                Worksheets("PO").Cells(i, "C").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partnumber, oRngDataBase, 3, False) ' QTY
                Worksheets("PO").Cells(i, "D").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(partnumber, oRngDataBase, 4, False) ' PRICE
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until i > LAST_ROW
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set oRngDataBase = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: might have to test if the Vlookup fails when it finishes.

Comment: I like the reasoning. Xabier's method works that way now, with an exit command. Thank you very much for your contribution.